# Hello everyone I have problem with QFile , could not open it for writing

Tags: c++, qt

```
QString numbers(ui->lineEdit->text());

if (!numbers.isEmpty())
    numbers.append(" ");

QFile file(":/Files/Numbers.txt");
if(!file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Append | QIODevice::Text))
    qDebug() << "Cannot open file" << file.errorString() << file.error() ;
```

file is attached to .qrc

and it outputs "Unknown error" with code 5

Comment: `QFileDevice::OpenError 5 The file could not be opened.` Are you sure the file exists in the resources and is seen under the correct path?

Comment: yes path was correct , problem was that resource system not allows to write files

Answer (score 3):

[Qt Resource](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html) Files are *read-only* because they are compiled into the binary and writing to them would probably require You to decompile them somehow. It is not clearly stated in the docs that the resource files can not be written to, but unfortunately this is the case - You can only *read* the files in Your resource system.